# How to select from a table adding a sequence column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sequence, sybase, sap-ase

Given a table `MY_TABLE` in a Sybase database, consisting of `COLUMN_A`, `COLUMN_B`, `COLUMN_C`, `SORTER_COLUMN`, I want to select as follows:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, SORTER_COLUMN, SEQUENCE
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_C = 'SOMETHING'
ORDER BY SORTER_COLUMN
```

Where `SEQUENCE` represents the sequence as sorted by `SORTER_COLUMN` -starting from 1, 2, 3, ...etc. How can I achieve that in Sybase?

I used to insert the records in a new table containing a column `SEQUENCE` defined as **IDENTIFIER**. But I need a solution to add a sequence directly into the select without having to insert into a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the later versions of Sybase (at least version 12) you can either use the [NUMBER(*)](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbreference/number-function.html) function:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, SORTER_COLUMN, Number(*) as SEQUENCE
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_C = 'SOMETHING'
ORDER BY SORTER_COLUMN
```

Or the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbreference/row-number-function.html) function

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, SORTER_COLUMN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SORTER_COLUMN) SEQUENCE
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COLUMN_C = 'SOMETHING'
ORDER BY SORTER_COLUMN
```

**UPDATE:**

As amyassin commented below both of the above functions are not working in Sybase 15.7 despite a fact that they are documented in the specification. Therefore, the only option you have in my opinion is to use a correlated query, like this:

```
SELECT b.COLUMN_A, b.COLUMN_B, b.SORTER_COLUMN, 
(select count(*)+1 from MY_TABLE a where a.SORTER_COLUMN < b.SORTER_COLUMN) as SEQUENCE
FROM MY_TABLE b
WHERE b.COLUMN_C = 'SOMETHING'
ORDER BY b.SORTER_COLUMN
```

Comment: I am using Sybase 15.7 `Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7` but both functions are not supported.

Comment: I have added a workaround solution. Check the updated answer

Comment: That is absolutely what I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a local variable that is incremented for every row. Initialize it in the FROM clause, where you must give it an alias.

```
SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, SORTER_COLUMN, (@n := @n + 1) AS SEQUENCE
FROM MY_TABLE, (SELECT @n := 0) as WHATEVER;
```

Comment: Looks like [MySQL] syntax